# How to configure OpenWrt to use as an ethernet to wifi bridge?

Tags: wireless-networking, openwrt

Here is the situation:

I have an HP LaserJet printer that has a built-in print server. But it does wired ethernet only, and I need it to be connected by Wifi instead.

So I bought a GL.iNet GL-MT300N V2 which is a tiny Wifi router with two ethernet ports, a 802.11n radio, and is OpenWrt capable.

My plan was to power the router off the printer's USB plug, connect the ethernet from the printer to the LAN on the router, and have the router join the Wifi network as a client.

I followed these instructions: https://openwrt.org/docs/guide-user/network/wifi/relay_configuration

I am able to get the router onto the Wifi network, and I can see it gets an IP from the DHCP server on that network.

But I can't get the printer to get a DHCP lease this way.

It also bothers me that the instructions say that I should be using WDS, a layer 2 GRE tunnel, or a mesh network instead of that method. I'm not certain what these things are, and whether OpenWrt can do them.

Furthermore, I don't need the router to get an IP address. I want the printer connected to it to get an IP address.

So my question is: how do I set it all up so that I can connect the printer's ethernet port to the OpenWrt router and have it connect through the OpenWrt router to my wifi network as if the printer had a built-in Wifi card?

Comment: Yes, it turns out that the OEM's firmware was actually running openwrt, and when you click "advanced settings", it brings you to a full LuCI interface. And there is a switch for WDS client mode which does exactly what I wanted.

Comment: I'm using WPA2, I think you might be confusing with WPS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the default firmware from the manufacturer *is* running OpenWrt. How great is that?! If I click "advanced settings", it brings me to a full LuCI web interface to OpenWrt.

The basic interface has an option to set WDS in client mode, and it does exactly what I was looking for with minimal configuration on my part.